# How do I make a natural-looking map from some Voronoi regions?

Tags: procedural-generation, maps

I'm using Voronoi regions to create a map for my game, much like [this](http://bl.ocks.org/mbostock/6675193). However, the lines are too straight and perfect. How do I make the borders more natural looking? As in, less like US state borders and more like international borders in Europe or Asia.

Comment: Try merging some adjacent cells randomly.

Comment: When anyone mentions *map* and *Voronoi* anywhere near each other, I think of [this series of map generation studies](http://simblob.blogspot.jp/2010/09/polygon-map-generation-part-1.html) from the perpetually fantastic [Amit Patel](http://www-cs-students.stanford.edu/~amitp/). I highly recommend checking them out.

Comment: I don't completely understand what this question is about. Which parts of the Voronoi map are you treating as countries? (Each cell, or some combination?) Do you want a map you can use *in gameplay*, or is this just a background visuals thing?

Comment: @Anko each cell is a country yes. Is that weird? I want to use it in gameplay but I recognize that that might bring additional challenges.

Comment: @Harry Remember Voronoi regions are guaranteed to be convex, which is why your results resemble US state borders. Most countries' borders have lots of concave features, so msell's suggestion of merging some adjacent cells would likely be more realistic. Arthur's image processing solution won't cut it if you want to have the shapes for use in your game's data model.

Comment: @Anko Thanks I'm taking the merging cells approach. Is there a solution for the data model? I can only think of either just increasing the number of vertices and then merging or just giving up pixel perfect accuracy when used in gameplay.

Comment: @Harry If the merged cells look good, you could use them just like that. [Amit's map generation tutorial that I linked earlier](http://www-cs-students.stanford.edu/~amitp/game-programming/polygon-map-generation/) has a section called *Noisy Edges* in which he describes a geometric method for introducing natural noise to coastlines. (That would still allow you pixel-perfect accuracy if you need it.)

Comment: The borders you're looking at often are based on water or mountains. Noisy edges look more natural than straight edges, so add some sort of noise. Arthur's answer uses waves; I used 1D midpoint displacement for my polygon maps; check out [this article](http://www.avanderw.co.za/midpoint-displacement-in-one-dimension/) with its demo. Either works. If you add a lot of noise, the borders might cross; see the Noisy Edges section of [my article](http://www-cs-students.stanford.edu/~amitp/game-programming/polygon-map-generation/) for how to add constraints to help prevent that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Simply add smooth noise in the form of waves of different amplitudes and frequencies.
You would need to add more vertices and split these edges. You could use a noise map to compute nice looking points based on the original edges at random.

Here is some working code:

```
/*****************************************************************************
 * Artur Wulf White - 18/1/14
 *****************************************************************************/

<languageVersion: 1.0;>

kernel Pres3D
<   namespace : "AWW37";
    vendor : "Arthur";
    version : 1;
    description : "Add noise to map"; >
{
    input image4 src;
    input image4 src2; // some smooth random colorful noise
    output float4 dst;

    parameter float4 coeffx;
    parameter float4 coeffy;

    void
    evaluatePixel()
    {
        const float2 imgSize = float2(512.0, 512.0);

        float2 c2D = (outCoord() / imgSize) - float2(0.5, 0.5);

        float4 tmp = sampleLinear(src2, outCoord());
        c2D.x += tmp.x * coeffx.x + tmp.y * coeffx.y + tmp.z * coeffx.z + tmp.w * coeffx.w;
        c2D.y += tmp.x * coeffy.x + tmp.y * coeffy.y + tmp.z * coeffy.z + tmp.w * coeffy.w;
        if(outCoord().x < imgSize.x && outCoord().y < imgSize.y){
            dst = sampleLinear(src, (c2D + float2(0.5, 0.5)) * imgSize);
        } else{
            dst = float4(0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0);
        }

    }
}
```

And the result:

[image]

I used Pixel Bender for prototyping quickly. Can be re-written in another language.